# error: ‘Class’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, templates, declaration

I would like to ask, how can I define class inside another one.  In the code below. I try to define it in the way   #define "CCompField.h" ,but it doesn't work. :(.
I think that it is very common programming problem, probably it was 100000 times solved on the internet, but I don't know how to find it. Thanks for help.

```
#ifndef CNEWGAME_H
#define CNEWGAME_H

class CNewGame{
    public:
               CNewGame();
              ~CNewGame();

        void  BeginnerGame();
        void  IntermediateGame();
        void  AdviceGame();
        void  HowToPlay();
        void  NetGame( int mode );


        int MoveInMenu();

    protected:
        void  Intro();
        void  Animation ();
        void  Menu(int);
         int  MoveInNetMenu();
        void  NetMenu(int);

        void  HeadOfGame();
template <class T> void BodyOfGame(CCompField & b, T & a);
        void  FooterOfGame();
};

#endif
```

It makes following errors.

```
In file included from src/CNewGame.cpp:12:0:
src/CNewGame.h:37:36: error: ‘CCompField’ was not declared in this scope
src/CNewGame.h:37:45: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
src/CNewGame.h:37:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
src/CNewGame.h:37:52: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
src/CNewGame.h:37:53: error: variable or field ‘BodyOfGame’ declared void
```

Comment: Any reason you have the header guard twice?

Comment: no i don't have it twice. I make only mistake during copy

Comment: Great. If the answer is the same as one of the ones below select it as the correct answer. If not, post the correct answer as an answer to your question and select that as the correct answer.

Comment: answer was that I included only class CCompField

Comment: As a new user I can't answer my own question in less then 8 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `#define "CCompField.h"` you need to include it:

```
#include "CCompField.h"
```

You also have an extra pair of

```
#ifndef CNEWGAME_H
#define CNEWGAME_H
```

but only one closing `#endif`.  You don't need the second pair of `#ifndef`/`#define`

Comment: of course I tried it as #include "CCompField.h" / I made mistake by creating of post :S/

Comment: Then you must have CCompFiled.h in the same directory as the oher files (or at least on the include path your compiler uses)

Comment: I find The solution

I tried to include only CCompField

but it was needed to include

#include "CField.h"
#include "CCompField.h"
#include "CCommonField.h"
becouse it is subclass of them.

I appreciate your answers. sorry for little chaos. I am new here.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to define it in the way #define "CCompField.h" ,but it doesn't work. :(

You need to figure out the header file where `CCompField` is defined and `#include` (not `#define`) it from `CNewGame.h`.

Comment: I find The solution

I tried to include only CCompField

but it was needed to include

#include "CField.h"
#include "CCompField.h"
#include "CCommonField.h"
becouse it is subclass of them.

I appreciate your answers. sorry for little chaos. I am new here.